# Tensor-matrix mode-$n$ product with matrix as right hand operand

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, tensors, tensor-decomposition

Kolda et al. and De Lathauwer et al. talk about the mode-$n$ tensor-matrix product where if $X,Y \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N \times N}$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$, we have
\begin{equation*}
Y = X \times_n C
\end{equation*}
such that $Y_{(n)} = CX_{(n)}$ where $Y_{(n)}, X_{(n)}$ are mode-$n$ unfolded forms of $X$ and $Y$.

What kind of formalism do I need to be able to refer to a product such that $Y_{(n)} = X_{(n)}C$ i.e. to describe a product in which the matrix is the right hand operand?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand that product but I don't understand what you're asking. "What kind of formalism ..." - what do you want to know? What's the problem?

Comment: I mean what well-established term/name e.g. mode-$n$ product/Hadamard product etc. or concept e.g. Tucker/CP decomposition etc can I use to refer to that concept? Or should I just define a function, say, $f : \mathbb{R}^{N \times N \times N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N \times N \times N}$ and say that it represents this product?

Comment: I propose three formalisms to describe the mode-$n$ product: 1. connecting the corresponding edges of the tensor and the matrix using graphical notation (see Graph Notation for Arrays - Ehrbar 2000) (which is the same as tensor networks notation, btw); 2. Just saying that you perform matrix-matrix product for each submatrix of the tensor $X$; 3. Just writing out the [einsum](https://rockt.github.io/2018/04/30/einsum)

Comment: @CrabMan Thanks for the info. I'd accept an answer saying there is no well-known term to refer to this product (so we can close this question).